# Changing state of messages which are "in delivery"

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, spring-batch, hornetq

In my application, I have a queue (HornetQ) set up on JBoss 7 AS. 
I have used Spring batch to do some work once the messages is received (save values in database etc.) and then the consumer commits the JMS session.
Sometimes when there is an exception while processing the message, the excecution of consumer is aborted abruptly.
And the message remains in "in delivery" state. There are about 30 messages in this state on my production queue.
I have tried restarting the consumer but the state of these messages is not changed. The only way to remove these 
messages from the queue is to restart the queue. But before doing that I want a way to read these messages so 
that they can be corrected and sent to the queue again to be processed.
I have tried using QueueBrowser to read them but it does not work. I have searched a lot on Google but could not 
find any way to read these messages.

I am using a Transacted session, where once the message is processed, I am calling:

```
session.commit();
```

This sends the acknowledgement. 
I am implementing spring's

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.SessionAwareMessageListener
```

to recieve messages and then to process them.
While processing the messages, I am using spring batch to insert some data in database. 
For a perticular case, it tries to insert data too big to be inserted in a column. 
It throws an exception and transaction is aborted.

*Now, I have fixed my producer and consumer not to have such data, so that this case should not happen again.*

But my question is what about the 30 "in delivery" state messages that are in my production queue? I want to read them so that they can be corrected and sent to the queue again to be processed. Is there any way to read these messages? Once I know their content, I can restart the queue and submit them again (after correcting them).

Thanking you in anticipation,

Suvarna

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the Transaction mode you are using.

for instance if you use transactions:

```
   // session here is a TX Session 
   MessageConsumer cons = session.createConsumer(someQueue);
   session.start();
   Message msg = consumer.receive...
   session.rollback(); // this will make the messages to be redelivered
```

if you are using non TX:

```
   // session here is auto-ack
   MessageConsumer cons = session.createConsumer(someQueue);
   session.start();
   // this means the message is ACKed as we receive, doing autoACK
   Message msg = consumer.receive...

   //however the consumer here could have a buffer from the server...
   // if you are not using the consumer any longer.. close it
   consumer.close(); // this will release messages on the client buffer
```

Alternatively you could also set consumerWindowSize=0 on the connectionFactory.

This is on 2.2.5 but it never changed on following releases:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/flow-control.html

I"m covering all the possibilities I could think of since you're not being specific on how you are consuming. If you provide me more detail then I will be able to tell you more:

Comment: Hi Clebert, Thank you very much for your quick and detailed response. It helped.
I have edited my question have more details. Can you please help?

Comment: I already answered it.. you have to either call rollback when your thing is failing.. or close it. if you leave it open it will stay that way.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. But I don't understand, I am unable to read the 30 "in delivery" state messages. The consumer 
reads and processes new messages added to the queue but the old messages are not read. I tried creating another consumer 
as well, but these old messages seem to be stuck. :(

Comment: Messages are on the client cache ready to be consumed. Close the consumer and they will leave the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed read your messages in the queue using jmx (with for example jconsole)

In Jboss As7 you can do it the following way :
MBeans>jboss.as>messaging>default>myJmsQueue>Operations

`listMessagesAsJson`

**[edit]**

Since 2.3.0 You have a dedicated method for this specific case :

`listDeliveringMessages`

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-763